# how to insert binary string of 8 bit to a byte array

Tags: java, arrays, binary

I want to convert a number from 0 to 256 to a binary string and then store in byte array.

Is there another way to store binary representation in array?

please help me

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int x= 0;
    int i ;
    byte[] second = new byte[256];
    for (i=0; i<=256; i++) {
        String binaryStr = Long.toString(x,2);
        String output = String.format("%8s", binaryStr).replace(' ', '0');
        System.out.println(output);
        second[i] = output;
        x++;
    }
}
```

Comment: What values do you want in the byte array? The char `'1'` or the int `1`?

Comment: If you want char '1' then there is getBytes alternative.

Comment: Did you mean `0` to `255`? 256 requires *9* bits, 255 requires 8 bit - ie an unsigned byte. And therefore, do you want the result to be a `byte[8]` (not `byte[256]`)?

Comment: Why `for (i=0; i<256;i++){second[i]=(byte)i;}` does not suffice?